# Magento 2 installation settings - mysql database password problem

Tags: magento2, database, setup

I am trying to run the magento 2 install (default shown below). However, if I add a symbol into the password it complains and says

```
Your password must include both numeric and alphabetic characters.
```

However, mysql won't let my create a user without a symbol in it.

so things like "iHateMagento1357"  won't be accepted by mysql  but
"iHateMagento1357~"  or "iHateMagento!13"  won't be accepted by Mag2.

Any suggestions..? before I go mad and use woocommerce instead.

====setup script reference====

```
bin/magento setup:install \
--base-url=http://localhost/magento2ee \
--db-host=localhost \
--db-name=magento \
--db-user=magento \
--db-password=magento \
--backend-frontname=admin \
--admin-firstname=admin \
--admin-lastname=admin \
--admin-email=admin@admin.com \
--admin-user=admin \
--admin-password=admin123 \
--language=en_US \
--currency=USD \
--timezone=America/Chicago \
--use-rewrites=1
```

Comment: I think there is some problem with your Magento installation. I personally use passwords like Welcome!2, admin@123, @dmin123, etc. in my localhost for my Magento installations and it works for me always.

Comment: Hmm thanks for that, something is on the wonk.

Comment: DOh ....it meant the admin password!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was referencing the admin password and not the mysql password. What a fool.

Answer (score 0):

Please Chengde both password

--db-password="d7zri8vFkX4MNdJ"
--admin-password="Ketan1234Diyan"

Like this one working fine